# ¿Cómo pongo una variable en un selector jQuery que está en un if?

Tags: javascript, jquery

estoy haciendo una pequeña app de BI, en la cual necesito hacer esto.

```
if( $('#'val ).length > 0){
```

Lo que quier hacer es `IF($(# MI_VARIABLE_ID))`, si el selector de ID (con id mi variable) haga tal cosa.

Necesito saber como llamar una variable dentro del selector de jQuery al mismo tiempo dentr del if, sabiendo que dentro del selector de `jQuery = $( )`, debe ir dento de comillas, por lo tanto la variable deberia estar encerrada entre las mismas

Quedaría algo así `if ( $("'#' +mivariable") )`, pero al estar entre comillas lo toma como un string.

No sé como llamar a la variable dentro del selector y menos dentro del `if`.

---

```
if( $('#'+val ).length > 0) {

    console.log("YA EXISTE UN DIV CON ESE ID");

} else {

   return FALSE;

};
```

Lo que intento hacer es algo así. Lo que pasa es que yo tengo una variable que tiene el valor de un input.

```
var val = VALOR DE INPUT.
```

mi app lo que hace es que el valor de input que vos pones apretás un botón y asigna ese valor que vos pusiste como ID de un DIV. Yo lo que quiero hacer es que no haya 2 div con id igual.

Por lo tanto quiero hacer que Si ID del div . length > 0 (esto se fija si existe o no) diga que no se puede poner ese nombre porque ya existe
si no todo bien. Lo que pasa es que al poner el if, no puedo poner con jQuery la variable en el como ID, porque me toma todo por igual.

Este es mi código:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var MaxInputs       = 10; //Número Maximo de Campos
    var contenedor      = $("#contenedor"); //ID del contenedor
    var AddButton       = $("#agregarCampo"); //ID del Botón Agregar



    //var x = número de campos existentes en el contenedor
    var x = $("#contenedor div").length + 1;
    var conteo = x-1; //para el seguimiento de los campos

    $(AddButton).on('click', function(e) {

        if(x <= MaxInputs){ //maximos de secciones impresas

              var val             = $("#input").val();
              var cambio          = $("#input").change();

          if(val==""){
            alert("Por favor ponle nombre a la sección que vas a crear");
            $('#input').focus();
            return false;
          }else{

            conteo++;
            //agregar campo
            $(contenedor).append('<div id="'+ val +'" class="seccion-'+ conteo +'" placeholder="Texto '+ conteo +'"><ul> AS</ul><a href="#" class="eliminar">&times;</a></div>');
            $('.btnAgregarComentario').click(function( event ) {
              //CREA UN LI ADENTRO DEL UL DE LA SECCIÓN QUE HEMOS CREADO
                $('#contenedor div ul').append('<li>¡Felicidades! Has insertado un nuevo DIV en el BODY</li>')

            });
            }
          x++; //INCREMENTA EL NUMERO
        };



  if( $('#'+val ).length ) {

    console.log("tetetetetete");

  } else {

   return alert("El nombre que intentas poner ya existe en una sección");

  };



    });






    $("#contenedor").on("click",".eliminar", function(e){ //click en eliminar campo
        if( x > 1 ) {
            $(this).parent('div').remove(); //eliminar el campo
            x--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Y como saben, el jQuery el selector después del `$()` debe ir dentro de comillas, esa es mi inquietud.

Comment: Vamos por parte. Quieres evaluar si selecciona un selector?

Comment: Solo debes concatenar correctamente la variable haciendo uso del `+` , dentro del `IF`,  `if($('#'+val ).length>0){...}`

Answer (score 5):

es como sigue:

```
if( $( "#"+MI_VARIABLE_ID ).val().length > 0){
```

Answer (score 2):

Según lo que entiendo, quieres poner una *variable* dentro de un *selector* de `jquery` para evaluar la propiedad `length` de este, por lo que se aprecia en tu código tienes problemas de sintaxis, deberías corregir tu código más o menos así:

```
var mi_id_selector = 'input_id';
// En javascript se usa el operador + para concatenar correctamente cadenas
if($('#' + mi_id_selector).val().length > 0){
    // Haz lo que necesites
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Al parecer lo que quieres saber es si el selector `MI_VARIABLE_ID` existe o si el largo del valor `MI_VARIABLE_ID` es mayor a 0, en ambos caso lo podrás saber con la propiedad `length`

ejemplo:

```
 if ($("#MI_VARIABLE_ID").length) {
   console.log("existe "+$("#MI_VARIABLE_ID").length+" elemento MI_VARIABLE_ID");
  } else {
   console.log("el elemento MI_VARIABLE_ID no existe");
  };
```

o

```
 if ($("#MI_VARIABLE_ID").val().length) {
   console.log("existe "+$(".MI_VARIABLE_CLASS").length+" elemento MI_VARIABLE_ID");
   console.log("su valor es: "+$(".MI_VARIABLE_ID").val());
   console.log("y su length es: "+$(".MI_VARIABLE_ID").val().length);
  };
```

La propiedad `length` no solo te dirá si existe el elemento sino que también te dirá cuantas veces existe, el siguiente ejemplo te lo explica mejor:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("input").on("change",function () {
  if ($(".MI_VARIABLE_CLASS").length) {
   console.log("existe "+$(".MI_VARIABLE_CLASS").length+" elemento MI_VARIABLE_CLASS");
   console.log("su valor es: "+$(".MI_VARIABLE_CLASS").val());
   console.log("y su length es: "+$(".MI_VARIABLE_CLASS").val().length);
  } else {
   console.log("el elemento MI_VARIABLE_CLASS no existe");
  };
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Al modificar se producira el evento onChange
<br><input class="MI_VARIABLE_CLASS">
<br><input class="MI_VARIABLE_CLASS">
```

Sin embargo como notaras en el ejemplo la propiedad .va() te indicara el valor del primer elemento.

Espero esto te ayuda, Saludos.. ;))